# Adding padding arount Items container in DataGrid wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, datagrid, controltemplate

I want to add left and right padding/margin for items in DataGrid.
I've tried various of methods, searched a lot, asked AI and nothing have worked out.
More specifically:

- I want only 'container' containing items inside DataGrid to have padding (not all individual cells, because I'd have to somehow distinguish where to which side of them add that spacing)
- I don't want column headers to have that padding/margin
- I don't want scrollbar to appear (which always happend when I tried to modify default ControlTemplate in many different ways)
- I want items inside to shrink depending on how much padding you give to the containter
- Preferably, I want to do this only in xaml

[image: Picture explaining what I want exactly]

```xml
<DataGrid
    ItemsSource="{Binding Leaderboard.PlayersScores}" <!--list of objects with Name and BestScore-->
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    RowHeaderWidth="0" 
    CanUserResizeColumns="False"
    CanUserResizeRows="False"
    BorderThickness="0"
    
    <!--[...]-->

    RowStyle="{StaticResource DataGridRowStyle}"  <!-- deleting margin,padding,border -->
    CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}" <!-- controlTemplate for items,background -->
    ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle}" <!-- some font,margin,padding-->
    Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}"   <!-- deleting margin -->
    Padding="1"
    >
    
    <!-- I wish I could just add some border with padding around that -->
    <DataGrid.Columns >
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Nickname" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="BestScore" Binding="{Binding BestScore}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    

</DataGrid>
```

If you want full code from that file you can check out my [repo](https://github.com/blackcaer/Snake/blob/main/Snake/MainWindow.xaml)
(I am learning basics of wpf now so I do realise that it looks terrible)

I've tried:

- Adding padding/margin to every possible element of it
- ControlTemplate with border /grid&border/[many other combinations] around ItemsPresenter ScrollViewer
- Asking chatgpt to do that, didn't work
- many other